# Generating XML in Dataweave

Tags: xml, dataweave, mulesoft

Good Morning,

I’m sending up a flare here. I am attempting to map over an object and generate XML. The code I have that does that is:

```
output application/xml
ns v1 http://services.visa.com/cam/v1
ns ns3 http://services.visa.com/cam/v2015_02
---
Accounts: {(vars.Accounts map 

    ns3#ContainerItemBaseType @("xsi:type": 'ns3:CardAccountTypeExp') : {
    ns3#UpdateType : "Add",
    ns3#Key : {
        ns3#UniqueId: "0",
        ns3#LastMaintenanceTimeStamp @("xsi:nil": 'true'): null,
        ns3#UniqueIndexId: "0",
        ns3#Pan: vars.newpan, 
        ns3#Plastic @("xsi:nil": 'true'): null
               },
    ns3#AccountNumber: $.AccountNumber,
    ns3#AccountTypeCode: $.AccountTypeCode,
    ns3#AccountType: $.AccountType,
    ns3#InstitutionId: $.InstitutionId,
    ns3#AccountQualifier @("xsi:nil": 'true'): null,
    ns3#AccountDescription @("xsi:nil": 'true'): null,
    ns3#ServiceLine: $.ServiceLine,
    ns3#ServiceLineCode: $.ServiceLineCode,
    ns3#IsFunding: $.IsFunding,
    ns3#AccountIndicator: "Primary",
    ns3#HasCreditAccess: true,
    ns3#HasDebitAccess: true,
    ns3#AccountOpenedDate @("xsi:nil": 'true'): null,
    ns3#AccountCurrencyCode_x0020_: "840",
    ns3#AccountNickName: $.AccountNickName,

  }
)}
```

This generates the following XML:
[xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEdAN.png)

This is ALMOST right. I want to be able to remove the surrounding `Accounts` tags. Does any one know how I do this?

Thanks in advance for any help

Dean
.

Here is the full XML that needs to be generated. Each container type is surrounded by an  tag that make each of the containers valid. I need to generate two CardAccountTypeExp containers

```
  <ns3:Items>
    <ns3:ContainerItemBaseType xsi:type="ns3:DigitalCardInfoTypeExp">
      <ns3:UpdateType>Add</ns3:UpdateType>
      <ns3:Key>
        <ns3:UniqueId>0</ns3:UniqueId>
        <ns3:UniqueIndexId>0</ns3:UniqueIndexId>
        <ns3:Pan>4153423278</ns3:Pan>
        <ns3:Plastic xsi:nil="true"/>
      </ns3:Key>
      <ns3:LastUsedTimestamp xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:UpdateTimestamp xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:MaintenanceTimestamp xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:StatusCode xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:ActivationType>NotActivated</ns3:ActivationType>
      <ns3:CardStatusSourceId xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:TransactionAccess>
        <ns3:Withdrawals>true</ns3:Withdrawals>
        <ns3:Deposits>true</ns3:Deposits>
        <ns3:Inquiries>true</ns3:Inquiries>
        <ns3:PaymentsTo>true</ns3:PaymentsTo>
        <ns3:PaymentsFrom>true</ns3:PaymentsFrom>
        <ns3:TransfersTo>true</ns3:TransfersTo>
        <ns3:TransfersFrom>true</ns3:TransfersFrom>
        <ns3:Purchases>true</ns3:Purchases>
        <ns3:ThirdPartyPayment>true</ns3:ThirdPartyPayment>
      </ns3:TransactionAccess>
      <ns3:PinFailCount>0</ns3:PinFailCount>
      <ns3:LimitGroupId>L14408</ns3:LimitGroupId>
      <ns3:LastCardstatusTimestamp xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:LastActivationTimestamp xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:Version xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:DigitalActive>false</ns3:DigitalActive>
    </ns3:ContainerItemBaseType>
    <ns3:ContainerItemBaseType xsi:type="ns3:Track2InfoTypeExp">
      <ns3:UpdateType>Add</ns3:UpdateType>
      <ns3:Key>
        <ns3:UniqueId>0</ns3:UniqueId>
        <ns3:LastMaintenanceTimeStamp xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ns3:UniqueIndexId>0</ns3:UniqueIndexId>
        <ns3:Pan>4156743278</ns3:Pan>
        <ns3:Plastic xsi:nil="true"/>
      </ns3:Key>
      <ns3:PinAuthFlag>false</ns3:PinAuthFlag>
      <ns3:PinAuthUpdateValue xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:ExpirationDate>
        <ns3:MM>10</ns3:MM>
        <ns3:YY>24</ns3:YY>
      </ns3:ExpirationDate>
      <ns3:PinAuthStatus>NaturalPinOffsetUsed</ns3:PinAuthStatus>
      <ns3:DefaultToExtExpDate>false</ns3:DefaultToExtExpDate>
      <ns3:PrevCardActivationStatus>None</ns3:PrevCardActivationStatus>
      <ns3:IssueActive xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:VersionField>01</ns3:VersionField>
      <ns3:PinChangeEmailFlag>N</ns3:PinChangeEmailFlag>
      <ns3:PinChangeCellPhoneFlag>N</ns3:PinChangeCellPhoneFlag>
      <ns3:EmailNotificationRecordID xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:CellPhoneNotificationRecordID xsi:nil="true"/>
    </ns3:ContainerItemBaseType>
    <ns3:ContainerItemBaseType xsi:type="ns3:CardAccountTypeExp">
      <ns3:UpdateType>Add</ns3:UpdateType>
      <ns3:Key>
        <ns3:UniqueId>0</ns3:UniqueId>
        <ns3:LastMaintenanceTimeStamp xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ns3:UniqueIndexId>0</ns3:UniqueIndexId>
        <ns3:Pan>415378</ns3:Pan>
        <ns3:Plastic xsi:nil="true"/>
      </ns3:Key>
      <ns3:AccountNumber>043701</ns3:AccountNumber>
      <ns3:AccountTypeCode>SAV</ns3:AccountTypeCode>
      <ns3:AccountType>Savings</ns3:AccountType>
      <ns3:InstitutionId>59954</ns3:InstitutionId>
      <ns3:AccountQualifier xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:AccountDescription xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:ServiceLine>Savings</ns3:ServiceLine>
      <ns3:ServiceLineCode>SAV</ns3:ServiceLineCode>
      <ns3:IsFunding>false</ns3:IsFunding>
      <ns3:AccountIndicator>Primary</ns3:AccountIndicator>
      <ns3:HasCreditAccess>true</ns3:HasCreditAccess>
      <ns3:HasDebitAccess>true</ns3:HasDebitAccess>
      <ns3:AccountOpenedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:AccountCurrencyCode_x0020_>840</ns3:AccountCurrencyCode_x0020_>
      <ns3:AccountNickName/>
    </ns3:ContainerItemBaseType>
    <ns3:ContainerItemBaseType xsi:type="ns3:CHBillingAddressTypeExp">
      <ns3:UpdateType>Add</ns3:UpdateType>
      <ns3:Key>
        <ns3:UniqueId>0</ns3:UniqueId>
        <ns3:LastMaintenanceTimeStamp xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ns3:UniqueIndexId>0</ns3:UniqueIndexId>
        <ns3:Pan>4153422086743278</ns3:Pan>
        <ns3:Plastic xsi:nil="true"/>
      </ns3:Key>
      <ns3:AddressExp>
        <ns3:Line1>1700 *********2</ns3:Line1>
        <ns3:Line2/>
        <ns3:Line3/>
        <ns3:City>BERKELEY</ns3:City>
        <ns3:State>CA</ns3:State>
        <ns3:ZipCode>947093402</ns3:ZipCode>
        <ns3:CountryCode>USA</ns3:CountryCode>
      </ns3:AddressExp>
      <ns3:RecordNumber>01</ns3:RecordNumber>
      <ns3:IsPreferred>Y</ns3:IsPreferred>
    </ns3:ContainerItemBaseType>
    <ns3:ContainerItemBaseType xsi:type="ns3:CardholderNameItemTypeExp">
      <ns3:UpdateType>Add</ns3:UpdateType>
      <ns3:Key>
        <ns3:UniqueId>0</ns3:UniqueId>
        <ns3:LastMaintenanceTimeStamp xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ns3:UniqueIndexId>0</ns3:UniqueIndexId>
        <ns3:Pan>4153422086743278</ns3:Pan>
        <ns3:Plastic xsi:nil="true"/>
      </ns3:Key>
      <ns3:NameExp xsi:type="ns3:NameTypeExp">
        <ns3:FirstName>M****A</ns3:FirstName>
        <ns3:LastName>F*****ES</ns3:LastName>
        <ns3:MiddleInitial>M</ns3:MiddleInitial>
        <ns3:Suffix/>
        <ns3:Title/>
      </ns3:NameExp>
      <ns3:IsPrimary>true</ns3:IsPrimary>
      <ns3:Version xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:RecordNumber>01</ns3:RecordNumber>
      <ns3:PreferredFlag>Y</ns3:PreferredFlag>
      <ns3:NameType>PN</ns3:NameType>
    </ns3:ContainerItemBaseType>
    <ns3:ContainerItemBaseType xsi:type="ns3:CustomerEmailTypeExp">
      <ns3:UpdateType>Add</ns3:UpdateType>
      <ns3:Key>
        <ns3:UniqueId>0</ns3:UniqueId>
        <ns3:LastMaintenanceTimeStamp xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ns3:UniqueIndexId>0</ns3:UniqueIndexId>
        <ns3:Pan>4143278</ns3:Pan>
        <ns3:Plastic xsi:nil="true"/>
      </ns3:Key>
      <ns3:EmailType>Personal</ns3:EmailType>
      <ns3:EmailAddress>PILOE.COM</ns3:EmailAddress>
      <ns3:Version xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ns3:RecordNumber>1</ns3:RecordNumber>
      <ns3:IsPreferred>Y</ns3:IsPreferred>
    </ns3:ContainerItemBaseType>
    <ns3:ContainerItemBaseType xsi:type="ns3:CellPhoneItemTypeExp">
      <ns3:UpdateType>Add</ns3:UpdateType>
      <ns3:Key>
        <ns3:UniqueId>0</ns3:UniqueId>
        <ns3:LastMaintenanceTimeStamp xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ns3:UniqueIndexId>0</ns3:UniqueIndexId>
        <ns3:Pan>4153422086743278</ns3:Pan>
        <ns3:Plastic xsi:nil="true"/>
      </ns3:Key>
      <ns3:VersionField>01</ns3:VersionField>
      <ns3:RecordNbrField>1</ns3:RecordNbrField>
      <ns3:PreferredFlagField>Y</ns3:PreferredFlagField>
      <ns3:VerifyDataField>707768/USA/</ns3:VerifyDataField>
      <ns3:Number>7068</ns3:Number>
      <ns3:Country>USA</ns3:Country>
      <ns3:TextOpt xsi:nil="true"/>
    </ns3:ContainerItemBaseType>
    <ns3:ContainerItemBaseType xsi:type="ns3:CardIssuanceInfoTypeExp">
      <ns3:UpdateType>Add</ns3:UpdateType>
      <ns3:Key>
        <ns3:UniqueId>0</ns3:UniqueId>
        <ns3:LastMaintenanceTimeStamp xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ns3:UniqueIndexId>0</ns3:UniqueIndexId>
        <ns3:Pan>4157278</ns3:Pan>
        <ns3:Plastic xsi:nil="true"/>
      </ns3:Key>
      <ns3:PreviousPAN>4153569</ns3:PreviousPAN>
    </ns3:ContainerItemBaseType>
  </ns3:Items>
```

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: `<Accounts>` is the root tag. If you remove it the output would not be valid XML, unless you replace it by a different root tag. And DataWeave does not generate invalid XML anyway. Please add an example of the expected output, as text, no images.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do would create an invalid XML output. `<Accounts>` is the root tag of the XML document. If you remove it then the output would not be valid XML, unless you replace it by a different root tag. Whatever is supposed to consume that output will reject it as invalid. And it is not possible to emit an invalid XML with DataWeave using output application/xml.